# How do i implement Location Based Service in my web application? except $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] .. In PHP

Tags: php, service, network-programming, ip, tracking

I want to know how to implement Location Based service in my website where i can find the exact location of the user who is accessing my site.. I tried with $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], but its giving ISP IP .. which is a bit inaccurate..

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently implemented geolocation with [GeoIP](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_GeoIP/redirected) (a PEAR package). It is not terribly accurate, but it gives country ok, region/state ok and major nearest city almost always right.

Once you install the package, you have to download the latest data file from [maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/php), and it can be as easy to use as this:

```
require_once "Net/GeoIP.php";
$geoloc = Net_GeoIP::getInstance('/var/www/GeoIP.dat');
try{
    $countryCode = $geoloc->lookupCountryCode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
}
catch(Exception $e) {}
```